# Referencing images from template

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-templates

I want to insert an image into my template. The image resides in the same folder as the template.

I tried:

```
<img src = "imageName.png" />
```

but for some reason, this wouldn't work.

Does anyone have an idea why that is?

Answer (score 1):

Don't put images in the same folder as templates. Images are a part of static content. You should read about [managing static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/) in django.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't intend to put images in the same folder as the templates, but for the sake of testing I tried, if the above line works, since specifying a relative path to a picture alo did not work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're new to the whole django scene, so don't be afraid to hit a few boulders on the way. In fact, this is a problem that I faced too, since I just usually put everything on a web-server, with an `index.php` file (yes, the horror), and everything was just relative.

So, let me give you a little context, what you are trying to embed on a page is called a *static file*. What that basically means is a file that does not change, a file that is not *dynamic*. Now, since these *static files* require no processing, they are treated specially, and are put inside a *static* folder. You can see where your static folder is when you check your main `settings.py` file.

Now often, people make a lot of mistakes with static files, because there are so many variables that have a `STATIC` infront of them. I know, its totally counter-intuitive, but there are reasons why they're there. [So, let me direct you to something that can be a little help in understanding this whole fiasco](http://blog.doismellburning.co.uk/2012/06/25/django-and-static-files/).

When using static files, you usually use a few special tags. You can learn more about them [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/). But, I'll just show you how you would embed your image into your html, just as a sample.

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<img src="{% static "images/myphoto.png" %}"/>
```

So, how should your directory look like? Well, what you would have is something like this

```
STATIC_FILES_FOLDER > IMAGES > myphoto.png
```

Hope that helps.